# Is there a way for multiple users to use an SQLite/SpatiaLite db simultaneously?

Tags: sqlite

Is there a way that multiple users can use the SQLite / SpatiaLite database simultaneously?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can, but with some limitations.  Spatialite is based on SQLite.  The permissions are handled by whatever permissions are applied to the actual file, so a given user (or all users) will have to have appropriate access the file.  As for concurrency, read is concurrent, write is serial:

http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5

Answer (score 1):

From what I know spatialite is a powerful client side geodatabase, but does not handle multiple logins, permissions and multiple users.
There is an interesting discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!searchin/spatialite-users/%5C%5BSpatiaLite-Users%5C%5D%2420Spatialite%2420geodatabase%2420for%2420QGIS%2420%243A%2420How%2420to%2420limit%2420writing/spatialite-users/zb6DP-Q8uMU/9xxbeqxq0GEJ)